# CASE statement in where clause in tsql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports

I'm trying to write a case statement in the where clause for a query I am working on. I am importing the code in Crystal reports and I am basically trying to say if the variable 'type' is set to 'create' run for this date range in the where clause else run for a different date range. It keeps giving me an error. I can't seem to identify what is wrong with my syntax here. Help anyone?

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME
DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME
DECLARE @type VARCHAR(20)
SET @Date1 = '2010-1-1'
SET @Date2 = '2010-2-1'
SET @type = '{?DateType}'

select *
from filled
WHERE   
    (CASE WHEN @type = 'create' THEN 
    filled.CREATEDON >= @Date1
    AND filled.CREATEDON < DATEADD(d, +1, @Date2)
    WHEN @type <> 'create' THEN   
    filled.datefilled >= @Date1
     AND filled.datefilled < DATEADD(d, +1, @Date2) 
     END)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? And why do you have 2 checks for `@type='create'`?

Comment: But then why is marked against Crystal Report when it is all SQL

Comment: Because I am importing the query into crystal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need a `case` statement

```
WHERE ( (@type = 'create' and filled.CREATEDON >= @Date1 AND filled.CREATEDON < DATEADD(d, +1, @Date2) ) or
        (@type <> 'create' and filled.datefilled >= @Date1 AND filled.datefilled < DATEADD(d, +1, @Date2) ) 
      )
```

This leaves the non-sensical logic you have in the `case`statement.  Both conditions have the same value for `@type`.  I assume that is a typo.

Comment: Yes it was in fact a typo it should be <>. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Using a CASE expression in a where clause is possible, but generally it can be avoided, and rewritten using `AND/OR`, IN your case it would be:

```
WHERE(  @Type = 'create' 
    AND filled.CREATEDON >= @Date1 
    AND filled.CREATEDON < DATEADD(d, +1, @Date2)
    )
OR  (   @Type != 'create' 
    AND filled.datefilled >= @Date1
    AND filled.datefilled < DATEADD(d, +1, @Date2) 
    )
```

**HOWEVER** queries like this usually produce suboptimal plans. You should use `IF/ELSE` logic if possible:

```
IF @Type = 'create'
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Filled
    WHERE   Filled.CreatedOn >= @Date1
    AND     Filled.CreatedOn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date2)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Filled
    WHERE   Filled.DateFilled >= @Date1
    AND     Filled.DateFilled < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date2)
END
```

The reason for this is the value of @type is not known at compile time, therefore the optimiser does not know whether it will need to search on `DateFilled` or `CreatedOn`, therefore cannot plan to use an index on either column (if one exists), so will do a table scan regardless of the indexes available. Whereas if you separate the logic with `IF/ELSE` it does not matter what the value of @type is, a plan is created for each branch of the `IF`, and in each branch the optimiser knows which column will be searched, and can plan to use the appropriate index.

You can also use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Filled
WHERE   Filled.CreatedOn >= @Date1
AND     Filled.CreatedOn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date2)
AND     @Type = 'create'
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    Filled
WHERE   Filled.DateFilled >= @Date1
AND     Filled.DateFilled < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date2)
AND     @Type <> 'create';
```

Again, if indexes exist on `DateFilled` or `CreatedOn` this is much more likely to produce a plan that uses them than using `OR`.